# Upload an LMDB file from dropbox into google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, dropbox, lmdb

I want to upload LMDB file from dropbox into storage of google colab with following code

```
!wget https://www.dropbox.com/sh/..../tr.lmdb?dl=0&lst=
```

LMDB files uploaded with named by `tr.lmdb?dl=0&lst=` and it didn't work for following code.

```
env=lmdb.open('/content/tr.lmdb',max_readers=1,readonly=True,readahead=False,meminit=False,)
```

I removed `?dl=`from name of file but it didn't work again and couldn't extract to `.mdb file`. while it should be extract.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Dropbox shared links refer to the HTML preview page for the linked item, not the item's data itself.

You can modify these links for direct data access as documented here though: https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download